# CALayer maximum size

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer

Is there a maximum CALayer size?

I have a long vertical list with rootLayer and sublayers as items and after ~16k rootLayer's height I've got an error `CoreAnimation: surface WIDTH x HEIGHT is too large` in `[rootLayer addSublayer:]`.

Is there any way to make a really large layer?
I've tried to use `CATiledLayer` instead of `CALayer` without success.

**UPD**

Here is my code

```
static const NSSize itemSize = { 600, 100 };

#import "CAView.h"

@implementation CAView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];

    CATiledLayer* layer = [CATiledLayer layer];
    layer.tileSize = itemSize;

    self.layer = layer;
    self.wantsLayer = YES;

    return self;
}

- (void)addLayer
{
    static CGFloat itemY = 0.0;

    CATextLayer* layer = [CATextLayer layer];
    layer.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"item %ld", [self.layer.sublayers count]];
    layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor redColor] CGColor];
    layer.frame = NSMakeRect(0, itemY, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);

    [self.layer addSublayer:layer];

    itemY += itemSize.height;

    NSRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.height = itemY;

    self.frame = frame;
}

@end
```

When the view size becomes larger max OpenGL texture size I've got blinking in my view and "CoreAnimation: surface WIDTH x HEIGHT is too large" in console log.

Comment: In what way did you fail with CATiledLayer? It should be able to handle huge layers

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist the same way: "CoreAnimation: surface WIDTH x HEIGHT is too large" in console log and layer doesn't render correctly.

Comment: David is correct. The way to handle very large layers is by using CATiledLayer.

Comment: How have you configured the tiled layer? What is your tileSize and levelsOfDetail?

Comment: I've set `tileSize` to my item layer size. I've update my question and added the code.

Comment: There's some good blog posts out there talking about the gotchas of `CATiledLayer` e.g. [at Cocoa Is My Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/)